# What do lollipops do?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have got some lollypops and planted them. but what do they do apart from growing more?
can you use them for something later in the game?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lollipops can be used to make more lollipops, and when you have enough you can turn them into candy either by throwing them into the wishing well, or by investing in the mill.

Answer (score 8):

Along with what @fredley says, lollipops are also the currency used to purchase items from the Sorceress.